# Is there any way to have a file extension in a bundle name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

I would like to have define a bundle like this:

```
bundles.Add(
    new StyleBundle("~/style.css").Include(
        //...
));
```

If the bundle name is just `"~/style"` this works, but with the file extension it always returns a 404. I suspect the server searches for CSS and JS files on the drive and ignores the bundling system, but I can't find anyone else who is trying to include file extensions in bundle names. Is this possible to do without something like a URL rewrite?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could add the following to your `<system.webServer>` section in web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

This will ensure that requests for static resources such as `.js` and `.css` will pass through the managed modules and be intercepted by ASP.NET MVC.

As an alternative to enabling `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` for all requests you could configure them only for the urls you need to use. So inside the `<handlers>` add the following:

```xml
<handlers>
    <!-- ... -->
    <add name="scriptBundle" verb="*" path="script.js" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler, System.Web.Optimization" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="cssBundle" verb="*" path="style.css" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler, System.Web.Optimization" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Hmm, is there a less drastic solution that would only affect .js and .css files?

Comment: +1 but having `path="*.bundle.js"` will prevent the handler from running for real files.

Comment: I am wondering if the second solution (adding the individual handlers) has some drawbacks. It certainly appears to work in some cases but I did also ocassionally see an error like `Unhandled application error: System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler'` in our logs. Certainly, BundleHandler does not have a parameter-less constructor. How is this supposed to work (i.e. which behavior are qe relying on?)

Comment: re. my previous comment, I have confirmed the exception occurs for request that point to a proper bundle path but with a wrong bundle version parameter (e.g. `/x/bundle.js?v=12345`). I'm sure this can be fixed (and a proper 404 returned) with some other trickery....